# Simple Stats Question

Tags: probability

I am working on a very simple statistics problem, but I am unsure of two parts of the problem due to unfamiliar wording.

The question is as follows:

> Suppose there is a 30% probability that someone has had a flu shot this year. You select 10 people at random.
>
> (a) What is the probability that at least half of these people have had the flu shot?
>
> (b) Find the expected value and standard deviation of the *number* of those 10 who have received a flu shot.
>
> (c) Find the expected value and standard deviation of the *proportion* of those 10 who have received a flu shot.

I've completed part (a), simply using $P(x)=\frac{n!} {x!(n-x)!}P^{x}(1-P)^{(n-x)}$ for $P(5), P(6), P(7), P(8), P(9), $and $P(10)$, and then summing the results. The result was $P(5\leq X\leq 10)=0.15042$.

For parts (b) and (c) I am stuck due to not knowing the meaning of the words *number* and *proportion* in their context within the question.

My textbook gives the following definitions for the derived mean and variance of a binomial probability distribution.

> Let $X$ be the number of successes in $n$ independent trials, each with probability of success $P$. Then $X$ follows a binomial distribution with mean and variance:

$$\mu =E(X)=nP$$

and

$$\sigma_{X}^{2}=E[(X-\mu_{X})^{2}]=nP(1-P)$$

In terms of the question I am answering I would have $P=0.3$ and $n=10$. But there is clearly some other meaning. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I see no problem with what you did in part (b). The word *proportion* indicates that your random variable is not the number of people vaccinated, but the number of people vaccinated divided by the total number of people. For example, if 6 of the 10 people are vaccinated, $X=0.6$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have in essence given a full answer to (b).  The number of people in a sample of $10$ who have had the flu shot is a random variable $X$, with mean $np$ and variance $np(1-p)$, where $p$ is the probability that an individual has had the flu shot.

So the mean of $X$ is $3$, and the variance is $10(0.3)(0.7)$. The *standard deviation* of the random variable $X$ is the square root of the variance.

For (c), we are looking at a close relative of the random variable $X$. The *proportion* that received the flu shot is 
$\dfrac{X}{n}$.

This random variable is frequently denoted by $\overline{X}$.  In general, if $X$ is a random variable, and $Y=kX$, where $k$ is a constant, then 
$$E(Y)=E(kX)=kE(X),$$ and 
$$\text{Var}(Y)=\text{Var}(kX)=k^2\text{Var}(X).$$
 (I am using $\text{Var}$ for variance because it may be easier to read.)

Apply the above formulas, with $Y=\overline{X}=\dfrac{X}{n}$. So $k=\dfrac{1}{n}$. We find that
$$E(\overline{X})=\frac{1}{n}E(X)=\frac{1}{n}(np)=p,$$
and 
$$\text{Var}(\overline{X})=\frac{1}{n^2}\text{Var}(X)=\frac{1}{n^2}np(1-p)=\frac{p(1-p)}{n}.$$

In our situation, we have $p=0.3$, so the mean of the sample *proportion*, that is, the mean of $\dfrac{X}{n}$, is just $0.3$.

The variance of the sample proportion is $\dfrac{(0.3)(0.7)}{10}$. For the standard deviation, take the square root.